# Copy docker image to heroko registry through Azure devops

Tags: heroku, azure-devops

I have a build pipeline(*in Azure DevOps*) that pushes an image to the docker hub. I would also like to push the same image to the Heroku hub.

I tried to follow the [Heroku document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). But it asks for a login. I didn't find any way to login to Heroku through the Azure pipeline. Is there any way to login to Heroku using a token? Is there any other way through which I can push the docker image to Heroku?

Azure pipeline: https://dev.azure.com/abhishekgoenkapublic/github-projects/_build?definitionId=3

Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/abhishek1950/mean

GitHub Project: https://github.com/abhishekgoenka/mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku provides an environment variable to add an access token to execute its commands.

The `HEROKU_API_KEY` variable is used to assign access token. It is possible to generate the token through the panel in Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication

In order to pass the token to our agent job, we have to configure this variable in our pipeline. For this, in the Variables tab we will create a new key as shown in the image below.

[image]

Having configured the environment variable, we were able to add the necessary steps and commands.

[image]

- **Heroku Container Login**: Log in via the heroku CLI .

[image]

- **Docker Push**: Push the docker image to Heroku.

[image]